# Initializer element is not a compile-time constant error

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, compiler-errors

I am implementing [`IIViewDeckController`](https://github.com/Inferis/ViewDeck) into my app.

When I am trying to replace the IBAccount to go to that screen I get an error:

> Initializer element is not a compile time constant

The first section of the code is what I have now, and the `UIViewController` is from the `IIViewDeckController` that I want to use to load the `FirstAccountViewController` over.

```
-(IBAction)account{
    FirstAccountViewController* ab=[[FirstAccountViewController alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:ab animated:YES];
    UIViewController* leftController = [[UIViewController alloc] init]; 
}

UIViewController* leftController = [[FirstAccountViewController alloc] init]; 
IIViewDeckController* deckController =  [[IIViewDeckController alloc] initWithCenterViewController:self.centerController leftViewController:leftController
                                                                           rightViewController:rightController];
```

Comment: What are those variables doing outside of a method body? What are they for, and where are you trying to use them?

Comment: @JacquesCousteau they're the not-a-compile-time-constants (end sarcasm)

Comment: @H2CO3: I'm not sure if your sarcasm is directed at me; I know what the error means, but I'm trying to figure out what Max wants to do with the variables so that I can answer the question in a productive way.

Comment: @JacquesCousteau of course no. It's directed towards OP who should have rtfm.

Comment: @JacquesCousteau

I am I just trying to have that effect applied to that IBAction and have it load the FirstAccountViewController for that effect. I know that those lines don't work, I was just putting them both there to see what to do with it...Sorry still learning here :)

Answer (score 1):

You've declared global variables here:

```
UIViewController* leftController =
    [[FirstAccountViewController alloc] init]; 
IIViewDeckController* deckController =
    [[IIViewDeckController alloc] initWithCenterViewController:self.centerController leftViewController:leftController rightViewController:rightController];
```

and you're trying to initialize them without context (e.g. the parameters you pass -- there should be no global `self`).

You don't want a global variable here, and you cannot declare it as such because it cannot be initialized properly in this context, and because it's ill formed in C and ObjC.

I recommend using an ivar in this case.

Comment: Thanks so much. Still just getting use to objc so forgive me for not knowing..

Do I need to put the UIViewController in the IBAction class to be able to have that run when the button is pushed?

Comment: @MaxRoper there is no right answer -- it depends on your app's logic.

Answer (score 0):

```
UIViewController* leftController = [[FirstAccountViewController alloc] init]; 
IIViewDeckController* deckController =  [[IIViewDeckController alloc] initWithCenterViewController:self.centerController leftViewController:leftController rightViewController:rightController];
```

Yeah, that's wrong -- if you want to initialize global variables on startup (although you're not at all advised to use global variables), you'll need to use an initalizer function:

```
UIViewController *leftController;
IIViewDeckController *deckController;

__attribute__((constructor))
void __init()
{
    leftController = [[FirstAccountViewController alloc] init]; 
    deckController =  [[IIViewDeckController alloc] initWithCenterViewController:self.centerController leftViewController:leftController rightViewController:rightController];

}
```

Comment: Does that need to be applied as a global variable if I just want to have it work for that one page?

Comment: No, but since your original question contained global variables, I used them as well. Nevertheless, they're discouraged to use unless you have a very good reason to do so.