# Initialize an object with an Image

Tags: ios, image, initialization, init

I have a class named Company, and I want to rewrite the `init` method. I want to include a company logo in this method. I tried this:

```
- (id)init
{
self = [super init];
if (self) {
    self.companyName = @"";
    self.companyLogo = nil;
    self.companyDesc = @"";
    self.companyYear = 0;
}
return self;
}

- (id) initWithCompanyName: (NSString*)companyName companyLogo: ***(UIImage*)companyLogo***
 companyDescription: (NSString*)companyDesc foundationYear: (NSInteger)foundationYear
{
self = [self init];
if(self)
{
    self.companyName = companyName;
    self.companyLogo = companyLogo;
    self.companyDesc = companyDesc;
    self.companyYear = foundationYear;
}
return self;
}
```

Obviously it can't be UIImage. So what can I do to include an image in the initialization?

Comment: I don't understand the question? Why can't it be a property with an UIImage?

Comment: I tried it with UIImage, but I'm getting an "Initializer element is not a compile-time constant" error message...

Comment: What AlBeebe !!! Why chance - to + ??? Means change instance method to Class method… Without any logic for me…

Comment: yes you can use an UIImage. This is right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your class definition with this calling works fine:

```
UIImage *logo = [UIImage imageNamed:@"IMG_0424.JPG"];
Company *company = [[Company alloc]initWithCompanyName:@"iPichy" companyLogo:logo companyDesc:@"iPichy APP Development" foundationYear:2010];
```

Comment: I don't get it - I'm still getting the "Initializer element is not a compile-time constant" error. Even on the `UIImage *logo = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myLogo.png"];` line.

Comment: Nevermind the previous comment, I worked it out - had to place this code inside of the Singleton's sharedInstance initialization. Thank you!

Comment: See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10367267/initializer-element-is-not-a-compile-time-constant-error